# Необходимо получить значение с помощью адреса в памяти

Tags: python, python-3.x, web3.py

Имеется скрипт для перевода приватного ключа кошелька Ethereum в публичный

```
from web3 import Web3, TestRPCProvider
i = '758a4d2e3450fa30d9d27780d919b7e5018fe62ab8817d61948d69866ded3763' 
#пустой кошелёк для примера
w3 = Web3(TestRPCProvider())
w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(i)
```

Вывод -

```
eth_account.signers.local.LocalAccount object at 0x7f49af2a79e8
```

Как получить значение по этому адресу?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250625/access-memory-address-in-python

Comment: Не очень понятно что вы в итоге хотите получить...

Comment: @AndrioSkur хочу получить то, что находится по адресу, который выдаёт `w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount`

Comment: он дает вам готовый объект, работайте с ним. Для начала: `obj = w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(i)`, `print(obj, type(obj), dir(obj))`

Answer (score 1):

Команда

```
w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(i)
```

даёт не значение, а комплексный объект со своими "внутренностями". Так, для моей задачи достаточно изменить его на

```
w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(i).address
```

Для вывода всех возможных значений достаточно ввести

```
print(dir(w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(i)))
```

И спасибо @AndrioSkur за помощь в решении этого вопроса